# Keyboard shortcut with Shift in Mate

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

I installed Fedora 21 with Mate. When I tried to bind the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (for moving a window to some desktop), it tells me that I am already using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> for switching. I can't understand why it ignores the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Also I noticed some strange behavior in JetBrains IDE's (but the same default config on Debian distros works fine). For example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> doesn't move the line up/down. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

`xev` output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x2eb, subw 0x0, time 62367072, (462,151), root:(462,271),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x2eb, subw 0x0, time 62367366, (462,151), root:(462,271),
    state 0x14, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x2eb, subw 0x0, time 62367619, (462,151), root:(462,271),
    state 0x1c, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    atom 0x1ae (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 62367622, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    atom 0x1ae (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 62367623, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    atom 0x1ae (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 62367624, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    atom 0x1ae (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 62367624, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x2eb, subw 0x0, time 62367900, (462,151), root:(462,271),
    state 0x201c, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Run `xev` from a terminal and press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up on the xev window. Several paragraphs beginning with `KeyPress event` will appear in the terminal. On the third line of one of these paragraphs, you'll see `(keysym 0xff52, Up)`. At the beginning of the line, you should see `state 0xd`. If you see a different value for `state`, copy-paste all the paragraphs beginning with `KeyPress` or `KeyRelease` into your question.

Comment: It looks like you have something in your keyboard configuration that causes Ctrl+Alt+Shift to be mapped to something different (so you get `ISO_Next_Group` instead of `Shift`). This is due to the XKB configuration. I'm not familiar enough with XKB to tell you where to look or how to fix. What is your keyboard configuration exactly (language and other options)? If you have a keyboard configuration GUI with lots of checkboxes, one of them might be the cause of this behavior.

Comment: I got correct `Shift_L`, when press just `Shift`. Tried to search in keybord config, but nothing. I'll try to search something related to XKB.

Comment: @SergeyChizhik, have you resolved this ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana hi. Actually nope, I've decided to use Linux mint ;)