# Apply keyboard buttons combination on release

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, mate-desktop, lmde

I installed LMDE2 Mate, with repos pointing on Debian testing.

In Pycharm(Jetbrains IDE) I have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in order to call python console.

My problem is, when I am pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard layout switching event is being called. I have some other related problems as well.

I think it can be solved by configuring keyboard to apply presses on release(default Windows behaviour, AFAIK), as opposed to apply on press, but I couldn't find any references of how to do so.

I've seen this [question on StackOverflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186069/keyboard-shortcut-with-shift-in-mate), but haven't find any useful information there.

`xev` log for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 28863279, (-505,381), root:(507,666),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 28863709, (-505,381), root:(507,666),
    state 0x8, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    atom 0x1db (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 28863710, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    atom 0x1db (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 28863710, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    atom 0x1db (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 28863711, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    atom 0x1db (XKLAVIER_STATE), time 28863711, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 28865393, (-505,381), root:(507,666),
    state 0x2008, keycode 26 (keysym 0x6d5, Cyrillic_u), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d1 83) "у"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d1 83) "у"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 28865605, (-505,381), root:(507,666),
    state 0x2008, keycode 26 (keysym 0x6d5, Cyrillic_u), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (d1 83) "у"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 28867681, (-505,381), root:(507,666),
    state 0x2008, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 28867701, (-505,381), root:(507,666),
    state 0x2008, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

EDIT. [Layout switch shortcuts keys prevent me from using the same combination](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209520/debian-8-1-stretch-testing-cant-use-switch-language-keyboard-hotkeys-with) asks exactly the same question, no answer provided. Switching keyboard layout change to another shortcut is not an option.

Comment: have you resolved this ?

Comment: I moved to the Linux Mint 18, where this problem is not present.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But I would like to use other distributions than Ubuntu. Such as Manjaro or LMDE :(. I've been looking for a solutions for a very long time with no success !!